# Direction of rotation in GLM matrix, using quaternions

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, quaternions, glm-math

I am working on a 3D rendering setup (all math done with GLM for OpenGL), and it all works correctly, except for how I would prefer my transformations to work.
I create a matrix for each entity like so:

```
matrix = mat4(1);
vec3 scale = GetWorldScale();
vec3 pos = GetWorldPosition(); // Returns pos + parent->pos
quat rot = GetWorldRotationQuat(); // Returns parent->rot * rot

matrix = glm::translate(matrix, pos);
matrix *= mat4_cast(rot);
matrix = glm::scale(matrix, scale);

right = matrix[0].xyz;
up = matrix[1].xyz;
direction = matrix[2].xyz;
```

Using this, it generally works correctly, except that I'm not sure how to adjust part of it for preference. That is that, using this, translation on the X-axis is flipped (eg. left is positive, and forward is positive on the Z-axis, but I less discriminant with that), and rotation on the Y-axis is flipped.

Looking at other code for this purpose, it seems that many negate what I've used for direction (for the camera). I've done that as well, and translation is correct, but all axes of rotation are the opposite of what's preferred (though rotation on X is the same whether direction is negated or not).

I'm not quite sure what I should do to help correct this, except possibly negate X-axis translation and Y-axis rotation before usage, but I feel that that isn't the best way. Thoughts?

Comment: well, you got further with quaternions in one go than me in 2 years.

Comment: It's not clear what these directions mean. Or what these transformations mean. The world, generally speaking, doesn't have a rotation.

Comment: Gam: Well I could be using eulers here too (I have yet to understand/witness the advantage of quaternions, but they're usable).
Nicol: I get that, I think, but you know what I mean in the way that each axis should behave.

Comment: Please explain exactly what the `GetWorldPosition()` and `GetWorldRotationQuat()` functions do. Apparently there are parents, so I think you might have the transformation order within your hierarchy messed up.

Comment: They return what they say. If the transform has a parent, `GetWorldPosition()` returns `parent->GetWorldPosition() + position`, and if it doesn't, it returns just `position`, and `GetWorldRotationQuat()` does the same except `parent->GetWorldRotationQuat() * rotation` or just `rotation` if it has no parent. I have also another method of this, which is creating a local matrix and multiplying by a world matrix of the parent, which also works. The parents are retrieved in the correct order.

Comment: FIY, you can use e.g. @Andreas to notify a user when you add a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problems come from the fact that you mix the order of transformations, especially translation and rotation. Each of these transformations (scale, translation, and rotation) define how to transform one coordinate system into another.

Let's go through an example: You have one child object c and its parent p. They each have translation t, rotation r, and scale s. To keep it simple, each of these are 4x4 matrices. Currently you do

```
matrix = p.t * c.t * p.r * c.r * p.s * c.s
```

So imagine the local coordinate system of the child that's transformed by this matrix (xyz axes of length 1). Points are multiplied from the right, so we have to read it right to left. First, the coordinate system gets scaled by the child, then scaled by the parent. Then it gets rotated by the child. Then by the parent. And now the child's translation is applied. That means the child translation is applied in a rotated coordinate system. Since you already applied both the child's **and** the parent's rotations, it's rotated into the parent's coordinate system. So the coordinates of the child are interpreted as if they were parent coordinates.

So what you should be doing: In your method, compute the object matrix `m = c.t * c.r * c.s`. Then the world matrix of your object is defined as `wm = pm * m`, where the parent matrix `pm` is the world matrix of the parent. That way you'll end up with a world matrix:

```
c.wm = (c.pm) * (c.o) = (p.t * p.r * p.s) * (c.t * c.r * c.s)
```

And that means that the child's translation is in the coordinate system of the child, and the parent's translation is in the coordinate system of the parent.